# How to populate SQL table by external file in Java

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I have the following table in SQL:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| PERSON_ID  | int(8)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| LAST_NAME  | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| FIRST_NAME | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| STREET     | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CITY       | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and this file: Person.data;

1, Smith,John,Old Street 99,London
   2, Rossi, Antonio, P.zza Croce 17, Roma

Now I want to populate the Person table with the records on the file.

I checked on google, even on Stackoverflow, but I found different philosophies to proceed, that say:

1) you can store the file directly into the table;

2) you need to fetch the String inside the file and split it by coma (,), after store them to the table;

3) before create an ArrayList from the file and after store it to the table;

Could you please clarify?

Follows my code:

```
public class MysqlCon {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner input;

        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test?useSSL=false", "root",
                    "db09");
            // here sono is database name, root is username and password
            java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            try {
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("/Users/Xim/Documents/workspace/DBDemo/src/Person.data");
                input = new Scanner(fileReader);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);

                    // use comma as separator
                    String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                    System.out.println(country[0]);

                }
                reader.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont see any attempt to store anything on your database???

Comment: Pick one method and try it, there is nothing right or wrong with any of the methods you suggest. Think, Horses for Courses and find one that suites you

Comment: @RiggsFolly: in fact I asking how I could proceed...

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I fixed it. Thank you for the incitement to believe in myself.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified that, and now it works properly:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] tmp = line.split(coma);
    person_id   = tmp[0];
    last_name   = tmp[1];
    first_name  = tmp[2];
    street      = tmp[3];
    city        = tmp[4];

     System.out.println(person_id + "\t" + last_name + "\t" + first_name + "\t" + street +"\t" + city );
     String sql = "INSERT INTO Person (PERSON_ID,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,STREET,CITY) "
            + "values ('" + person_id + "','" + last_name + "','" + first_name + "','" + street + "','" + city +"')";

     ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
     ps.executeUpdate();

}
reader.close();
```

Comment: Good on ya squire

Answer (score 0):

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO PERSONS(LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, STREET, CITY) "
        + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test?useSSL=false",
                "root", "rumpelstielchen");
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        Path file = Paths.get(
                "/Users/Xim/Documents/workspace/DBDemo/src/Person.data");
        Files.lines(path) // (path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .map(String::split("\\s*,\\s*", 4))
            .filter(words -> words.length == 4)
            .forEach(words -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    stmt.setString(i + 1, words[i]);
                }
                stmt.executeUpdate();
            });
    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        ...
    }
```

This assumes you make PERSON_ID AUTOINCREMENT, so the database fills in the ID itself (best).

It uses a PreparedStatement, for escaping the apostrophe and such.

Try-with-resources is an ugly syntax to automatically close connection and prepared statement, even on exception (or return).

I have read the file using java 8's stream, as it is shorter.

Split takes care of possible spaces around comma's (`\\s*`).

These are the basics of an import.

In more complex cases one could retrieve the generated primary key PERSON_ID with getGeneratedKeys. Also there are improvements possible (related commit, character set is important, batch possible).

Comment: sorry but I don't understand very well your code, maybe because in Java 8... I fixed it by myself; thanks

Comment: Yes, java 8 introduces too many features at once.